# How to use nohup properly within an ssh session invoked by gitlab-runner?

Tags: ssh, bash, gitlab, nohup

I use gitlab runner's ssh executor to access an embedded device via ssh. I want to run a script there.

Basically the script invokes an upgrade routine on the device using dbus. Simple enough, isn't it?

```
#!/bin/bash
dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=blabla /path blabla.swupdate.InitiateUpdate string:"" string:"" string:"$1"
sleep 4
dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=--dest=blabla /path blabla.UpgradeMode
```

Now the device will immediately reboot, causing the ssh connection with gitlab runner to terminate unexpectedly, which leads to a pipeline failure.

I came up which various script entries to detach the last dbus call from the ssh connection but to no avail.

Here is one thing I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=blabla /path blabla.swupdate.InitiateUpdate string:"" string:"" string:"$1"
nohup $(sleep 2 && dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=--dest=blabla /path blabla.UpgradeMode)&
echo "ready to disconnect ssh"
```

When I connect manually using ssh, executing the script and disconnect quickly manually using `exit`, I see the system reboot. But when `gitlab-runner` executes everything, the job succeeds, but the reboot does not happen. So I am sure that the `nohup`-command does not get fully executed.

I tried putting `nohup`in front of both the `sleep` and the `dbus-send` command, as well as trying to put `disown` after the parentheses. I also tried as suggested by a comment here, to put nohup in front of the script call in `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

None of that lead to success.

Any ideas, how to get this right?

Thanks

Comment: Try to run your script with nohup, e.g. `nohup ./myscript.sh`.

Comment: this was also not successful

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry this is so late. I've recently just had the same problem. Gitlab runner blocks on child processes, and any process in the child tree. This makes the `disown` command not work. Forking, and `nohup` also don't work.

The only solution I could figure out was using the `at` command https://linux.die.net/man/1/at

Basically I put my command in a script then did:

`at new < my_script.sh`. That successfully exited and kicked off my program in the background.

Comment: Do you mean `at now`?